# php check if file exist on multiple folders at the same time

Tags: php, file-exists

when i want to check if a file exist and if exist add a suffix i use the following code which is working fine

```
    $increment = ''; //start with no suffix
    while(file_exists($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/".$file_name . $increment . '.' . $extension)) 
    {
       $increment++;
    }
    $final_name = $file_name . $increment. '.' . $extension;
```

Now i have to check if the file exist in more that one folder and the names of the folders are in an array (and i can add or remove folders from this array);

```
$folders[] = "thumb";
$folders[] = "medium";
$folders[] = "large";
$folders[] = "xlarge";
```

Now i have to check if the file exist in all these folders.

If the file exist in one of this folders i have to add a suffix
check again until the file does not exist in all of these folders

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Just check the files existence iterating over the folders collected in that array. What is the question with that?

Comment: And a side note: trying to find a "not yet used" file name to save files typically is a sign of a bad approach to file name generation. Why is that required? Why can't you simply create file names that are guaranteed to be unique? It still makes sense to check, but that increment strategy is very unelegant.

Comment: @arkascha I cant create file names that are guaranteed to be unique when a user upload a file.So when the file is uploaded and i have to resize the image if the filename exist i have to add a suffix.In the case of one folder is very simple but in the case of checking multiple folders at the same time is more complicated and that why i posted the question

Comment: Why can't you do that? You state that like a fact, but _why_? Of course you can!

Comment: @arkascha the simplest answer is that a user can name the images for seo reasons the way he thinks its best and i have to upload the filenames as is, but when exist i add a suffix.It would much easier for me to rename files on upload using random string, or database id etc

Comment: You _never_ should accept a client side specified string for direct internal usage. You are not interested in the user specified file name at all as far as your local file system goes. Don't make that mistake to accept such names! What you do instead is: you create a unique, internal file name (file name prefix) to store uploaded files under and save that location in your database. If you have to you can also add the user specified file name in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll agree with @arkascha 's view that if the file is for internal use, using file name with unique hash will be better.

But if it's necessary,
Try use foreach() to check those prefix in your array at once.

```
function files_suffix_exists($file_name, $folders){
    $root = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"];
    if(file_exists($root."/".$file_name . '.' . $extension){
        return true;
    }
    foreach($folders as $folder){
        if(file_exists($root."/".$folder."/".$file_name . '.' . $extension){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

$folders[] = "thumb";
$folders[] = "medium";
$folders[] = "large";
$folders[] = "xlarge";


$increment = ''; //start with no suffix
while(files_suffix_exists($file_name, $folders))
   $increment++;
   $file_name .= $increment;
}

$final_name = $file_name . '.' . $extension;
```

Comment: i agree that for internal use is better the unique hash but i am not facing internal user.Your solution is awesome and i will try it in the next hour.Thanks

Comment: If I want to maintain the original name, I might use a table to keep the relationship between internal name and user's custom name anyway.

Comment: this will increase sql query.I think this would be an unnecessary query and i count each one i make to keep queries low

Comment: (Off original topic) There are many methods, in case to reduce the query a file based relation could also be maintained. e.g. When upload a file named "aaa.jpg" and hash it to 00ffccee.jpg on the server, at same time create a 00ffccee.txt and record original file name "aaa.jpg" inside. It'll take little extra storage space through.

Comment: Please understand that a _hash_ is _not_ necessarily unique. Use a micro time stamp instead. That _is_ guaranteed to be unique.

Comment: @HZS Creating an additional file to store the original name will create _much_ more overhead than storing the name in the database along with other things like a unique internal `id`, a timestamp and whatever. File system operations are _really_ expensive compared to database queries.

Comment: Also there is absolutely no sense in adding a dot (`.`) and an "extension" to the file name. What for?